# GridView update issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have not worked with the gridview data control much. I have a gridview that when the user clicks on Edit they have textboxes to fill in (Completed By, Completed Date, User Created, Number of Pages). When they click Update, I need the data inserted into the database and the record that was updated to be hidden  (or removed) from the gridview. The only part that I can not get to work is the updating of the database.

Here is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Job_No"  AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
        CssClass="label">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
               <%-- <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Iscomplete" HeaderText="Complete" 
                SortExpression="Iscomplete" />--%>

           <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed Date" SortExpression="Completed_Date" >
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_No" HeaderText="Job Number" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Job_No" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Report" HeaderText="Report" 
                SortExpression="Report" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete" SortExpression="Iscomplete">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                        Enabled="false"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed By" SortExpression="Completed_By">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompletedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed_By") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed_By") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed Date" SortExpression="Completed_Date">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompletedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed_Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Created" SortExpression="User_Created">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserCreated" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User_Created") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("User_Created") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number of Pages" 
                SortExpression="Number_of_Pages">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberofPages" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number_of_Pages") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number_of_Pages") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total Pages" 
                SortExpression="Total" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
                SortExpression="Amount" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Confidential" HeaderText="Confidential" 
                SortExpression="Confidential" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                SortExpression="Email" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Created" HeaderText="Date Requested" 
                SortExpression="Date_Created" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Needed" HeaderText="Date Needed" 
                SortExpression="Date_Needed" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time_Needed" HeaderText="Time Needed" 
                SortExpression="Time_Needed" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Building_Location" HeaderText="Building Location" 
                SortExpression="Building_Location" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Number_of_Copies" HeaderText="Number of Copies" 
                SortExpression="Number_of_Copies" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Paper_Size" HeaderText="Paper Size" 
                SortExpression="Paper_Size" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Account_Charged" HeaderText="Account Charged" 
                SortExpression="Account_Charged" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Two_Part_Paper" HeaderText="Two Part Paper" 
                SortExpression="Two_Part_Paper" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Three_Part_Paper" HeaderText="Three Part Paper" 
                SortExpression="Three_Part_Paper" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Cut_and_Pad" HeaderText="Cut and Pad" 
                SortExpression="Cut_and_Pad" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Collate_Only" HeaderText="Collate Only" 
                SortExpression="Collate_Only" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Single" HeaderText="Single" 
                SortExpression="Single" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Front_and_Back" HeaderText="Front and Back" 
                SortExpression="Front_and_Back" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Staple" HeaderText="Staple" 
                SortExpression="Staple" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Saddle_Stapling" HeaderText="Saddle Stapling" 
                SortExpression="Saddle_Stapling" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Reduction" HeaderText="Reduction" 
                SortExpression="Reduction" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Laminate" HeaderText="Laminate" 
                SortExpression="Laminate" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Folder_Stuffer_Sealer" 
                HeaderText="Folder Stuffer Sealer" 
                SortExpression="Folder_Stuffer_Sealer" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                SortExpression="Description" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name1" HeaderText="File Name 1" 
                SortExpression="File_Name1" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name2" HeaderText="File Name 2" 
                SortExpression="File_Name2" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name3" HeaderText="File Name 3" 
                SortExpression="File_Name3" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name4" HeaderText="File Name 4" 
                SortExpression="File_Name4" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name5" HeaderText="File Name 5" 
                SortExpression="File_Name5" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name6" HeaderText="File Name 6" 
                SortExpression="File_Name6" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name7" HeaderText="File Name7" 
                SortExpression="File_Name7" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name8" HeaderText="File Name 8" 
                SortExpression="File_Name8" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name9" HeaderText="File Name 9" 
                SortExpression="File_Name9" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name10" HeaderText="File Name 10" 
                SortExpression="File_Name10" ReadOnly="True" />



        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DuplicatingConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Duplicating_Request_Table] WHERE [Job_No] = @original_Job_No AND (([Date_Created] = @original_Date_Created) OR ([Date_Created] IS NULL AND @original_Date_Created IS NULL)) AND (([User_Created] = @original_User_Created) OR ([User_Created] IS NULL AND @original_User_Created IS NULL)) AND (([Email] = @original_Email) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND @original_Email IS NULL)) AND (([Building_Location] = @original_Building_Location) OR ([Building_Location] IS NULL AND @original_Building_Location IS NULL)) AND (([Number_of_Copies] = @original_Number_of_Copies) OR ([Number_of_Copies] IS NULL AND @original_Number_of_Copies IS NULL)) AND (([Date_Needed] = @original_Date_Needed) OR ([Date_Needed] IS NULL AND @original_Date_Needed IS NULL)) AND (([Time_Needed] = @original_Time_Needed) OR ([Time_Needed] IS NULL AND @original_Time_Needed IS NULL)) AND (([Paper_Size] = @original_Paper_Size) OR ([Paper_Size] IS NULL AND @original_Paper_Size IS NULL)) AND (([Account_Charged] = @original_Account_Charged) OR ([Account_Charged] IS NULL AND @original_Account_Charged IS NULL)) AND (([Two_Part_Paper] = @original_Two_Part_Paper) OR ([Two_Part_Paper] IS NULL AND @original_Two_Part_Paper IS NULL)) AND (([Three_Part_Paper] = @original_Three_Part_Paper) OR ([Three_Part_Paper] IS NULL AND @original_Three_Part_Paper IS NULL)) AND (([Cut_and_Pad] = @original_Cut_and_Pad) OR ([Cut_and_Pad] IS NULL AND @original_Cut_and_Pad IS NULL)) AND (([Collate_Only] = @original_Collate_Only) OR ([Collate_Only] IS NULL AND @original_Collate_Only IS NULL)) AND (([Single] = @original_Single) OR ([Single] IS NULL AND @original_Single IS NULL)) AND (([Front_and_Back] = @original_Front_and_Back) OR ([Front_and_Back] IS NULL AND @original_Front_and_Back IS NULL)) AND (([Staple] = @original_Staple) OR ([Staple] IS NULL AND @original_Staple IS NULL)) AND (([Saddle_Stapling] = @original_Saddle_Stapling) OR ([Saddle_Stapling] IS NULL AND @original_Saddle_Stapling IS NULL)) AND (([Reduction] = @original_Reduction) OR ([Reduction] IS NULL AND @original_Reduction IS NULL)) AND (([Laminate] = @original_Laminate) OR ([Laminate] IS NULL AND @original_Laminate IS NULL)) AND (([Folder_Stuffer_Sealer] = @original_Folder_Stuffer_Sealer) OR ([Folder_Stuffer_Sealer] IS NULL AND @original_Folder_Stuffer_Sealer IS NULL)) AND (([Description] = @original_Description) OR ([Description] IS NULL AND @original_Description IS NULL)) AND (([Number_of_Pages] = @original_Number_of_Pages) OR ([Number_of_Pages] IS NULL AND @original_Number_of_Pages IS NULL)) AND (([Total] = @original_Total) OR ([Total] IS NULL AND @original_Total IS NULL)) AND (([Amount] = @original_Amount) OR ([Amount] IS NULL AND @original_Amount IS NULL)) AND (([Iscomplete] = @original_Iscomplete) OR ([Iscomplete] IS NULL AND @original_Iscomplete IS NULL)) AND (([Completed_By] = @original_Completed_By) OR ([Completed_By] IS NULL AND @original_Completed_By IS NULL)) AND (([Completed_Date] = @original_Completed_Date) OR ([Completed_Date] IS NULL AND @original_Completed_Date IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name1] = @original_File_Name1) OR ([File_Name1] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name1 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name2] = @original_File_Name2) OR ([File_Name2] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name2 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name3] = @original_File_Name3) OR ([File_Name3] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name3 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name4] = @original_File_Name4) OR ([File_Name4] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name4 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name5] = @original_File_Name5) OR ([File_Name5] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name5 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name6] = @original_File_Name6) OR ([File_Name6] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name6 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name7] = @original_File_Name7) OR ([File_Name7] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name7 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name8] = @original_File_Name8) OR ([File_Name8] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name8 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name9] = @original_File_Name9) OR ([File_Name9] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name9 IS NULL)) AND (([File_Name10] = @original_File_Name10) OR ([File_Name10] IS NULL AND @original_File_Name10 IS NULL))" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Duplicating_Request_Table] ([Date_Created], [User_Created], [Email], [Building_Location], [Number_of_Copies], [Date_Needed], [Time_Needed], [Paper_Size], [Account_Charged], [Two_Part_Paper], [Three_Part_Paper], [Cut_and_Pad], [Collate_Only], [Single], [Front_and_Back], [Staple], [Saddle_Stapling], [Reduction], [Laminate], [Folder_Stuffer_Sealer], [Description], [Number_of_Pages], [Total], [Amount], [Iscomplete], [Completed_By], [Completed_Date], [File_Name1], [File_Name2], [File_Name3], [File_Name4], [File_Name5], [File_Name6], [File_Name7], [File_Name8], [File_Name9], [File_Name10]) VALUES (@Date_Created, @User_Created, @Email, @Building_Location, @Number_of_Copies, @Date_Needed, @Time_Needed, @Paper_Size, @Account_Charged, @Two_Part_Paper, @Three_Part_Paper, @Cut_and_Pad, @Collate_Only, @Single, @Front_and_Back, @Staple, @Saddle_Stapling, @Reduction, @Laminate, @Folder_Stuffer_Sealer, @Description, @Number_of_Pages, @Total, @Amount, @Iscomplete, @Completed_By, @Completed_Date, @File_Name1, @File_Name2, @File_Name3, @File_Name4, @File_Name5, @File_Name6, @File_Name7, @File_Name8, @File_Name9, @File_Name10)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Job_No, Date_Created, User_Created, Email, Building_Location, Number_of_Copies, Date_Needed, Time_Needed, Paper_Size, Account_Charged, Two_Part_Paper, Three_Part_Paper, Cut_and_Pad, Collate_Only, Single, Front_and_Back, Staple, Saddle_Stapling, Reduction, Laminate, Folder_Stuffer_Sealer, Description, Number_of_Pages, (Number_of_Copies * Number_of_Pages) AS Total, Amount, Iscomplete, Completed_By, Completed_Date, File_Name1, File_Name2, File_Name3, File_Name4, File_Name5, File_Name6, File_Name7, File_Name8, File_Name9, File_Name10, Report, Confidential FROM Duplicating_Request_Table WHERE (Iscomplete IS NULL)" 


        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Duplicating_Request_Table] SET [Number_of_Pages] = @Number_of_Pages, [Total] = @Total, [Amount] = @Amount, [Iscomplete] = @Iscomplete, [Completed_By] = @Completed_By, [Completed_Date] = @Completed_Date, report = @report WHERE [Job_No] = @original_Job_No">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Job_No" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Date_Created" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_User_Created" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Building_Location" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Number_of_Copies" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_Date_Needed" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Time_Needed" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Paper_Size" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Account_Charged" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Two_Part_Paper" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Three_Part_Paper" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Cut_and_Pad" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Collate_Only" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Single" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Front_and_Back" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Staple" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Saddle_Stapling" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reduction" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Laminate" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Folder_Stuffer_Sealer" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Number_of_Pages" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Total" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Amount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Iscomplete" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Completed_By" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Completed_Date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name3" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name4" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name5" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name6" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name7" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name8" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name9" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_File_Name10" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Created" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="User_Created" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Building_Location" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Number_of_Copies" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date_Needed" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Time_Needed" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Paper_Size" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Account_Charged" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Two_Part_Paper" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Three_Part_Paper" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cut_and_Pad" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Collate_Only" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Single" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Front_and_Back" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Staple" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Saddle_Stapling" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Reduction" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Laminate" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Folder_Stuffer_Sealer" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Number_of_Pages" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Total" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Iscomplete" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Completed_By" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Completed_Date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name3" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name4" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name5" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name6" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name7" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name8" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name9" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="File_Name10" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Number_of_Pages" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Total" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Iscomplete" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Completed_By" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Completed_Date" Type="String"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="report" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Job_No" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bindgridView();
        }
    }

    protected void bindgridView()
    {
    try{

        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.50.1.42;Initial Catalog=Duplicating;User ID=sa;Password=Zanestate$");
        string query = "Select * from duplicating_request_table";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter sqldt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        sqldt.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (ViewState["delRows"] != null)
            {

                int[] delIndices = (int[])ViewState["delRows"];

                int itemsLength = delIndices.Count(indx => indx != 0);

                //create the javascript array in the client side
                //push the deleted row indexes from c# array to javascript array
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script>");
                sb.Append("var indexArray = new Array;");
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("indexArray.push('" + delIndices[i] + "');");
                }
                sb.Append("</script>");

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "arrayScript", sb.ToString());

                //call the deleteRow function on the client side
              this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "del", "javascript:deletegrdvwRow()", true);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            bindgridView();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string itemname = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex][0].ToString();

            //TextBox txt_productName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_updtprod");
            Label JobNo = (Label)row.FindControl("Job_No");
            TextBox CompletedBy = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtCompletedby");
            TextBox CompletedDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtCompletedDate");
            TextBox UserCreated = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUserCreated");
            TextBox NumberofPages = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtNumberofPages");
            //    TextBox TotalPages = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];

            //write your logic here to update the data into the database
            SqlCommand sqlcon = new SqlCommand("update duplicating_request_table set Completed_By='" + CompletedBy.Text + "',Completed Date='" + CompletedDate.Text + "',User_Created='" + UserCreated.Text + "',Number_of_Pages='" + NumberofPages.Text + "'where Job_No='" + JobNo + "'");
            //SqlCommand sqlcon = new SqlCommand("UPDATE duplicating_request_table SET Completed_By=@Completed_By, Completed_Date=@Completed_Date, User_Created=@User_Created, Number_of_Pages=@Number_of_Pages WHERE Job_No=@JobNo");
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;


            //those rows which are deleted previously while updating store it's indexs
            if (ViewState["delRows"] == null)
            {
                int[] delIndices = new int[12];
                delIndices[0] = e.RowIndex;
                ViewState["delRows"] = delIndices;
            }
            else
            {
                int[] delIndices = (int[])ViewState["delRows"];

                int itemsLength = delIndices.Count(indx => indx != 0);

                delIndices[itemsLength] = e.RowIndex;
            }

            bindgridView();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            bindgridView();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            //while moving to the next page, clear the viewstate
            ViewState["delRows"] = null;

            bindgridView();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

I am not getting any errors - but the data is not being updated in the database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This C-sharpcorner article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/select-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/) describes you how to view, update, and delete data using an ASP.NET 2.0 GridView Control in SQL Server database and C#.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't executed your command.  You'll need something like:

```
sqlcon.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You'll also need to create the connection for this.

Comment: that is already done on the Adapter `SqlDataAdapter sqldt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and added a quick exception response(your 'try catch' routine you dont have anything that shows the response back to you when it catches the exception, that is why nothing is showing.) to check what exception presents... In my case what it came up was..

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Im hoping its because there is a firewall not letting me connect to your server, why dont you run it and let us know what the exception is

```
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);           

        }
```